# Why use numpy's log method to call ArrayBox instance, it will call ArrayBox's __len__, and __getitem__ methods

Tags: autograd

when i use autograd package, [autograd](https://github.com/mattjj/autodidact/tree/master/autograd)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from pprint import pprint
import autograd.numpy as np

import autograd.numpy
import numpy as anp

def f(y):
    return anp.log(y)
y = np.array([1, 2])
print(grad(f)(y))
```

I know that I need to use autograd's numpy's log method, But I want to know why can't use Numpy's log method

When I go to debug, it will call ArrayBox's **len**, and **getitem** methods,

```
class ArrayBox(Box):
    """Box for np.ndarray.

    Anything you can do with an np.ndarray, you can do with an ArrayBox.
    """

    # This class has no attributes.
    __slots__ = []  # 
    # Used by NumPy to determine which type gets returned when there are
    # multiple possibilities. Larger numbers == higher priority.
    __array_priority__ = 100.0

    @primitive
    def __getitem__(A, idx):
        return A[idx]
    # Constants w.r.t float data just pass though
    shape = property(lambda self: self._value.shape)
    ndim = property(lambda self: self._value.ndim)
    size = property(lambda self: self._value.size)
    dtype = property(lambda self: self._value.dtype)
    T = property(lambda self: anp.transpose(self))
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._value)
```

So what I want to ask is, when numpy executes the log method on the instance, will it call the `__len__` method and `__getitem__` method of the instance